# Медиа-запросы и псевдо-класс :lang()

Tags: css, вёрстка, media-queries

При переключении с английского на русский, ломается `header`. Проблема в том, что названия пунктов меню(которое в хедере) длинее названий на английском из-за чего кнопки авторизации сползают на следующую строку. Проблема решается тем,что нужно изменить размеры шрифта, которые устанавлвиаются в медиа-запросах при смене разрешения.Чтобы не менять размер шрифта для всех языков, я думаю использовать псевдо класс `:lang()`. То есть прописать отдельные медиа-запросы для русского хедера, однако это не работает. Обычный медиазапрос:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1720px){
    .navbar-nav > li > .menu_page{
        font-size: 22px;
    }
}
```

Медиазапрос для русского хедера:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1720px){
    .navbar-nav > li > .menu_page :lang(ru){
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть ошибка, или может быть такие вещи можно решить другим способом?Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пробел между `.menu_page` и `:lang(ru)`, вероятно, не нужен.